# How to parse file by row and split text

Tags: python

I am new to python.  Need a starting point or some guidance.  I need to parse a file by row and print a certain number.  Here is a sample of my input file:

3_12   1  F  4
4_20   3  J  7
12_17  3  G  6

The rows go on for much longer, but I'm trying to write a script to read the file and print the number after the '_' (12, 20, 17 in this example).

Comment: What language are you trying to use to get the values?
PowerShell Script?
C#?
JS?

Comment: Python, sorry for not specifying

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
import re
f = open("patch.txt","r")
contents = f.read()
f.close()

for row in contents.split("\n"):
    searchObj = re.search( r'^\d+_(\d+)\s', row)
    if searchObj:
        print(searchObj.group(1))
```

Output will be like:

```
12
20
17
...
```

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear.  I only need the 3 numbers, not the other stuff

Comment: @user3295538 No problem. Please check my updated answer.